# Permanently store thumbnails of images on Windows

Tags: windows, photos, thumbnails

When viewing a folder of images in "Large Icons" mode, I often see the thumbnails slowly regenerate. How do I permanently store those thumbnails so I don't have to wait ages whenever I open a folder? I'm using Windows Vista Business 64-bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This is](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/10794-thumbnail-cache-enable-disable.html) a good article about enabling and disabling thumbnail caching in several ways, also explaining why you may not want to have it enabled. You can change the default behavior by either a registry or a policy change.